# Flink - How to expose metrics with custom labels

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, flink-streaming

I am looking to publish/expose metrics with custom labels, the custom labels are not known before hand and we will only know at runtime. Foe eg., with micrometer we can perform the following

```
Metrics.counter("Ops", "type", type).increment(value);
```

with above, the type value changes dynamically and it simply is published to prometheus. How can we do the same in Flink?

I have the following class, but i will have no idea on the values which I can only know at runtime, so i cant pre-register then in open() function as below:

```
public class LogMetrics extends RichMapFunction<IndividualFeatureMetricHolder, String> {

    private MetricGroup metricGroup;

    @Override
    public void open(org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        this.metricGroup = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().addGroup("test");
    }

    @Override
    public String map(IndividualFeatureMetricHolder value) throws Exception {
        metricGroup.addGroup("test1", value.getMetricComputationLevel())
                .addGroup("test2", value.getMetricGroup())
                .addGroup("test3", value.getFeature())
                .gauge(value.getMetricType(), value::getValue);
        metricGroup.gauge(value.getMetricType(), value::getValue);
        return "";
    }
}
```

any suggestions would be helpful on how can we can achieve runtime tags in Flink.

ChatGPT is not helpful :)

Comment: i am aware the metric has to be pre-registered, i provided the gauge registration in map function to help understand the case I am looking for to register or use the gauge towards dynamic tags

Comment: Just a work of caution to OP, and whoever might read this question in future: [Don't overuse labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels). This whole described situation smells like a good candidate for cardinality explosion. Approach with dynamic labels described here is only OK, if you are reasonably sure values will not exceed something like 100 distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anything prevents you from registering a metric when it is first used (in the `map` function, for example), rather than in the `open`. Just keep track somehow of the fact that it has been registered, so you don't register it twice.